# Moving files in Applescript, got error: "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class."

Tags: macos, error-handling, applescript, file-moving

I am trying to move files using Applescript, and I get an error every time I run the app.  In the contents of the app, I have the file(s) I want to move (so if I distribute the app the users won't have to separately download the file(s)).  That is also why I am using `((path to home folder as text)` and adding the specific file path past that. Here is my code:

```
set source to ((path to home folder as text) & "/Contents/Resources/finder.jpg")
set source2 to ((path to home folder as text) & "/Contents/Resources/finder@2x.jpg")

set destination to alias "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:Dock.app:Contents:Resources:"

tell application "Finder"
    move source to destination with replacing
    move source2 to destination with replacing
end tell
```

p.s.  I checked just about every related question/answer there is on here, and none helped.

Answer (score 1):

a simple `display dialog source` would have led you to the solution:

1. `path to home folder` returns an **alias** to your **HOME** folder (Macintosh HD:Users:your name:). I think you wanted `path to me` instead which points to your app.
2. `analias as text` returns a path string using **:** as delimiters and you append parts that use **/** to delimit the path components
3. `analias as text` returns a path string that ends with **:** in case of directories

Summary: Try

```
set source to ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:finder.jpg")
```

**UPDATE:**
You can't use `alias ...`, better use is `... as alias` and I think, maybe `duplicate` is better here...

```
set source to ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:finder.jpg") as alias
set source2 to ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:finder@2x.jpg") as alias

set destination to "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:Dock.app:Contents:Resources:" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate source to destination with replacing
    duplicate source2 to destination with replacing
end tell
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: That has helped but I still get the error: "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class."  This error highlights `move source to destination with replacing` which leads me to think that there is something wrong with my method of moving.

Comment: I belive you need to add `file` in front of `"source"`

Comment: Good point! You can define all paths as aliases also. I updated my answer!

Comment: Now it's telling me `File Macintosh HD:Users:[my username]:Desktop:App.app:Contents:Resources:finder.jpg wasn’t found.`

Comment: Using Skript Editor open the bundle slider and look if the file is there. If not, drag it to that location.

Comment: After saving an App it is available in the upper right corner in script Editor. You have access to your bundle content there!

Comment: It's there under resources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73196/discussion-between-thatcrazycow-and-shooterko).